# Matrix representation in Java

Tags: java, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix in the following format:

```
rowName(String) colName(String) value(float)
```

in a tab separated text file. I want to convert this format into the following:

```
rowIndex(Integer) colIndex(Integer) value(float)
```

Comment: Do you want to load this into a data structure or write it back out into a new file? Could you give a (small) example of the contents of the file.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an TLongFloatHashMap e.g.

```
final TLongDoubleHashMap matrix = new TLongDoubleHashMap();

public void set(int x, int y, double value) {
    long key = ((long) x << 32) + y;
    matrix.put(key, value);
}

public double get(int x, int y) {
    long key = ((long) x << 32) + y;
    return matrix.get(key);
}
```

How you convert Strings to Integer is up to you.  There is no standard way of doing this as you have to know what the mapping should be for a matrix operation to make sense.

Comment: `TLongDoubleHashMap`/`TLongFloatHashMap` is not part of the Java Runtime Library, but a part of Trove, which you can get at http://trove.starlight-systems.com/